# Running mocha with blanket coverage causes the tests not to run

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, blanket.js

In my `package.json`, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require blanket -R html-cov > test/coverage.html --compilers coffee:'./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register'"
  },
```

So if I run `npm test`, I get:

```
 npm test

> my-site@1.0.0 test /Users/me/Sites/my-site
> mocha --require blanket -R html-cov > test/coverage.html --compilers coffee:'./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register'
```

If I take out the `blanket` stuff (`"test": "mocha --compilers coffee:'./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register'"`), then my tests run correctly.

I am using `CoffeeScript`, if that matters. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: are you using the coffeescript loader?

Comment: What does that mean and how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the blanket [documentation](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/docs/compatibility_and_features.md#coffeescript-in-the-browser):

> If your test runner tests source files written in coffee script,
>   blanket still has you covered. Using a custom loader, coffeescript
>   files are compiled, instrumented, and tested.

The coffee script [loader](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/docs/advanced_browser.md#loaders) is located in [node-loaders/coffee-script.js](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/src/node-loaders/coffee-script.js).
You will need to add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"config": {
    "blanket:" {
        "pattern" : "src", // use the correct pattern for your project
        "loader": "./node-loaders/coffee-script"
    }
}
```

For example see the blanket project [package.json](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/package.json) file.

In addition, the command line you are using for the tests is incorrect. It is missing the path to your test files and the output redirection should be at the end. You should use something like:

```
mocha --require blanket -R html-cov --recursive --compilers coffee:./node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register src > test/coverage.html
```

Comment: I have that:
`  "config": {
    "blanket": {
      "pattern": "src",
      "loader": "./node-loaders/coffee-script"
    }
  }`

no dice

Comment: @Shamoon see the additions to my answer

Comment: Just as a note, output redirection *does not* have to be at the end, for pretty much any shell. You can even put redirection *before* the command. If you don't believe me, go try running `< README.md cat -` on a UNIX-like.